# What is the time complexity in my single number code

Tags: python, performance, data-structures, dataset, big-o

The question is "Given an array of integers, every element appears twice except for one. Find that single one.

Note:
Your algorithm should have a linear runtime complexity. Could you implement it without using extra memory?"

My code is below:

```
def singleNumber(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums.count(nums[i]) == 1:
            return nums[i]
```

Why my code is not O(N)? did it calculate by for loop, which takes n rounds?

Thanks.

Comment: You have two loops there (even though you're not using another `for` loop). Count automatically creates another loop for each number you have. Which leads to worst case complexity of `O(n2)`

Comment: A solution can be achieved using Count Sort and forking it a little bit. However, that needs some extra memory space (if you do it correctly it takes less than the size of the array)

Answer (score 3):

We can do this using an xor command:

```
a = [0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9]
ans = 0
for i in a:
    ans = i^ans
ans
4
```

This works, as the xor is effectively doing (1^1)^(2^2)^4^(5^5), and we cancel all the doubles out.

Answer (score 0):

You code runs in O(N^2) because the `count` method runs in O(N) and it is executed inside of a for loop. Which in total gives you O(N^2).

If you want to make it run in O(N).

You can do the following:

1. Loop through the array and set its values as keys to a dict and the number of times it appears in the list as it key's value.
2. Then iterate through the key-value pairs of the dict again and look for the key whose value is `1`. This is will give O(2*N) which is O(N) time complexity.

Comment: That is just like using Counting Sort which I indicated in the comments. However, it fails to meet the requirement of (NO EXTRA SPACE). I really doubt, however, that it could be done without extra space.

Comment: @AmmarSalman It can be done using only one variable other than a looping index. Hint: use the `xor` function; aka `^` in Python.

Comment: @casevh I got what you're saying. Yes it works to find the only number mentioned odd number of times if every other number is mentioned even number of times.